# Confusing sentence from reddit

Tags: sentence

There was this reddit thread to see who can create the most confusing sentence.

Judging by the upvotes, I am guessing it is indeed a correct sentence. If so, can someone decipher this work of art? What exactly does this mean?

> Has Anyone Really Been Far Even as Decided to Use Even Go Want to do Look More Like?

Comment: It's gibberish.  Ignore it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not a coherent sentence.

It started life several years ago on the 4chan video games board (probably as a deliberate troll) and led to several people attempting to decipher it as a real question. Screenshots of this 4chan thread were then posted on reddit, and it has subsequently spread virulently from there.

Presumably, this explains why the reddit *cognoscenti* consider it worthy of their upvotes.

Comment: [More on the "sentence" on KnowYourMeme.com](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/has-anyone-really-been-far-even-as-decided-to-use-even-go-want-to-do-look-more-like)